# C# Entity - SQLite and Unicode (Greek )

Tags: c#, sqlite, unicode, entity

```
var q_truck = (from item in datagate.item
               join belong in datagate.belong on item.belong_id equals belong.id
               where item.plate.StartsWith(textBox1.Text)
```

So the problem here is when I use GREEK letters `.StartsWith` or `.Contains` doesn't work, they are fetching wrong results.

ConnectionString has that "charset=utf8" in line, string fields are `NVARCHAR`, Model properties of string fields have True in Unicode, on `modelContext` I added

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("NVARCHAR"))
```

, even erased the database made a new, made the string fields, as text/string/varchar ... nothing. English and numbers work just fine.

I have added all the necessary Nuget packages, even `Microsoft.Data.SQLite`.
I don't know what else to do, I'm trying to make it work 3 days now, no result!

Answer (score 0):

SQLite [FAQ](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18):

> Case-insensitive matching of Unicode characters does not work.
>
> The default configuration of SQLite only supports case-insensitive comparisons of ASCII characters.

You need SQLite with the ICU (International Components for Unicode) extension.

Comment: You are probably right , the ICU package for windows that i downloaded though , has no "allinone" file in it , as the instructions says. So for now , i choose to solve this by executing Entity Native SQL Query , like the ones that are described here : http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx